# cocoa - Unexpected outstanding background CATransaction

Tags: cocoa

I am developing a macOS application using cocoa.

I have a NSScrollView instance called scrollView and a custom view instance called customView, and I use

```
[scrollView setDocumentView:customView];
```

in my AppDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method.

But when I run this application, and use my track pad to scroll, the application crushes, the Xcode turns to the threads part and displays "libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:" and the instruction that fails is jae.

The console displays "Unexpected outstanding background CATransaction".

But!!! When I click the scroller of the NSScrollView and drags it, the application doesn't crush.

It is so strange and I have no way to solve it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same crash, which I *think* might be caused by a checkbox in a tableview cell... (UPDATE: I can confirm that removing the checkbox solves the crash. But why??)

Comment: @mrwheet I still have no idea about that problem...

Comment: I did figure out what was up. In my case, the data was being provided by an ArrayController in IB, but where I set its data source happened to be in a custom GCD queue. Popping that data update into a `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` solved the problem.

Comment: @mrwheet same here. I do have a checkbox but all of my updates are on the main queue. I do get a crash when I just scroll an empty tableview

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar issue. I had an outline view and as soon as I started to scroll, the app crashed with the "Unexpected outstanding background CATransaction" message.

All of the outline view's modifications were done on the Main Thread. 
I did however have a TableView where I used bindings and some of the KVO updates were done on a background thread.

As soon as I fixed these updates, the outline view didn't crash anymore, too.